Ngx-Stripe only allows googlePay and applyePay
I'm trying to add express checkout with ngx-stripe to my website with the options buttonType and get an error: 'paypal' does not exist in type 'ButtonTypeOption'.
Im confused because the documentation states that "Supported payment methods include Link, Apple Pay, Google Pay, and Paypal."
heres my code, I also have activated the payments on the stripe dashboard as well:
stripe = injectStripe(STRIPE_API_KEY)
  elementsOptions: StripeElementsOptions = {
    mode: 'payment',
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'usd',
    locale: 'es'
  };

  options: StripeExpressCheckoutElementOptions = {
    buttonType: {
      applePay: 'buy',
      googlePay: 'buy',
      paypal: 'buy'
    }
  };

<ngx-stripe-elements [stripe]="stripe" [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions">
                                <ngx-stripe-express-checkout [options]="options" />
                            </ngx-stripe-elements>

I've even attempted to alter the name from 'paypal' to other things such as 'paypalpay', but upon reviewing the source code for these literals it only seems to show applepay and googlepay. Is there any explanation for this or any potential workarounds?
Everything runs fine until i add the 'paypal' feature.
